# How to integrate a json data frame into an html file

Tags: html, json, d3.js, visualization

I'm currently "learning" d3js by myself and I found a lot of examples [here](http://d3js.org/). It seems that for all the visualizations we need two separated files. One is a script (an html file) and the other one is a json file which contains our data set.

I'm curious if there is a way to put the json file into html file so we can have only one file. I think I saw an example like this previously on the internet but I lost it.

The only reason I want to do it like this is that if data set is separated from html file, I cannot use Chrome to view my result (I think Chrome is blocking the script from reading local data set). I can use Firefox to open up my result but the animation doesn't perform smoothly.

Maybe some of my understanding is not really right. But if there is any suggestions please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just using one HTML file, you probably have a `<script>` tag on your page where all the code is located. You can define your data as a Javascript array.

It can be nice to use multiple files to organize code, data, and view elements (the HTML). [This](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally) page gives some help on setting your browser to let you do that.  For Chrome, close all open windows. Then run Chrome from the 'Run' prompt with this flag: `chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`